# Httppost not working - Getting a html response instead of JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json, http-post

I am trying to connect to the server using httppost but I can't due to some error.
This is my android code:

```
public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute(){}

        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try{

                URL url = new URL("http://abhirathod.byethost4.com/post.php");

                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
                postDataParams.put("name", "abc");
                postDataParams.put("email", "abc@gmail.com");
                Log.e("params", postDataParams.toString());

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));



                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                    conn.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";

                    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return sb.toString();

                }
                else {
                    return new String("false : "+responseCode);
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }



        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

        while(itr.hasNext()){

            String key= itr.next();
            Object value = params.get(key);

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

I am calling execute method once. I am getting this output:

https://s23.postimg.org/47dwhsxvf/Screenshot_2016_12_24_11_05_49_com_spellbee_admi.png

Plsz help!

Comment: You don't state the error you are getting.

Comment: Also state the server side code..We can't identify the problem without it..

Comment: Here is the php code

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/h1uSE

Comment: There is no error. The code is executing well but I am not getting the desired output. I am getting this output https://s23.postimg.org/47dwhsxvf/Screenshot_2016_12_24_11_05_49_com_spellbee_admi.png